# JNI jarray argument has non-array type

Tags: java, c++, qt, java-native-interface

In my Java code, i have a method as follows:

```java
HashSet<String> scanned_items = new HashSet<String>();

String[] getScannedBuffer() {
      String[] result = scanned_items.toArray(new String[0]);
      mReader.getInventoryBufferTagCount((byte) 0xff);

      return result;
}
```

and in my Qt code, I am calling it as such:

```cpp
QAndroidJniObject response("com/test/RfidReader");
response.callObjectMethod("getScannedBuffer","()[Ljava/lang/String;");
```

I am trying to iterate through the string array using the following code:

```cpp
QAndroidJniEnvironment env;
jobjectArray stringDataArray = response.object<jobjectArray>();
jsize dataArraySize = env->GetArrayLength(stringDataArray);
```

However, I am getting the following error: JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jarray argument has non-array type

Comment: `response.callObjectMethod("getScannedBuffer","()[Ljava/lang/String;");` -- What happened to the return value?

Comment: ohh.. u meant i have to QAndroidJniObject response2 = response.callObjectMethod("getScannedBuffer....); ? still new to JNI

Comment: Well, callObjectMethod returns a jobject.  That jobject is the `String []`.